# how to duplicate only one image in pygame

Tags: python

i am currently trying to make the happy ms chicken game in which a chicken gives an egg wherever you click. so i want to duplicate the egg but not the chicken.
here is my code:
#-----------------

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,600))
chickenx = 350
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','ds','sdf','dfss','dfsd','lj','ghgf','hgf']
chickeny = 250
egg = pygame.image.load('D:\\drive D\\Downloads\\Python apps\\happy chicken\\egg.png')
egg = pygame.transform.scale(egg, (150, 150))
screen.fill((0,78,255))
chicken = pygame.image.load('D:\\drive D\\Downloads\\Python apps\\happy chicken\\chicken.png')
chicken = pygame.transform.scale(chicken, (150,150))
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # print(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            # chicken.fill((0,0,0,0))
            chickenx = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
            chickeny = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]
            # print((chickenx, chickeny))
            # screen.fill((0,78,255))
            # chicken.fill(()
            print('new egg')
            # screen.blit(chicken, (chickenx,chickeny))
            # # screen.fill((0,78,255))
            screen.blit(egg, (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]-50, pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]-50))
            # pygame.display.update()
            screen.blit(chicken, (chickenx,chickeny)) 
    b = random.choice(lst)
    # chicken.fill((0,0,0,0))
    b = screen.blit(chicken, (chickenx,chickeny))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score -1):

## Solution

### Preventing Chicken Duplicates

First of all, move `screen.fill((0,78,255))` into the `while` loop so that you can hide all the previous frames. This will prevent the problem you are experiencing, which is multiple chickens on the screen.

### The Egg Class

Next, create a class called `Egg` for the eggs. This class will be used to create and draw eggs.

```
class Egg:
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y, egg):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.egg = egg

    def draw(self):
        self.surface.blit(self.egg, (self.x, self.y))
```

As you can see, this class takes four parameters: surface, x, y and egg.

- **surface**- the pygame window (the screen variable in your code).
- **x**- the x position of the egg.
- **y**- the y position of the egg.
- **egg**- the image of the egg.

This class also contains one method called `draw`. In this method, the image of the egg is being displayed on the screen using `self.surface.blit` which is just like `screen.blit` in your code.

### The Eggs List

Because we clear the window in every frame, there is only one chicken on the screen at a time. But, this also means that there will only be one egg on the screen at a time. So this is where the `Egg` class is used. First, create a list called `eggs` for storing the eggs. Then, when the mouse button is down, create a new `Egg` object and set its `x` to the mouse's `x` position subtracted by 50 and set its `y` to the mouse's `y` position subtracted by 50. Next, append the `Egg` object to the `eggs` list. And lastly, draw the chicken.

#### Like this:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    chickenx, chickeny = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    print('new egg')
    eggObject = Egg(screen, chickenx-50, chickeny-50, egg)
    eggs.append(eggObject)
    screen.blit(chicken, (chickenx,chickeny))
```

Under the event loop, we iterate over the `eggs` list. For each egg in the `eggs` list, draw the egg.

#### Like this:

```
for e in eggs:
    e.draw()
```

### Full Code

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900,600))
chickenx = 350
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','ds','sdf','dfss','dfsd','lj','ghgf','hgf']
chickeny = 250
egg = pygame.image.load('D:\\drive D\\Downloads\\Python apps\\happy chicken\\egg.png')
egg = pygame.transform.scale(egg, (150, 150))
chicken = pygame.image.load('D:\\drive D\\Downloads\\Python apps\\happy chicken\\chicken.png')
chicken = pygame.transform.scale(chicken, (150,150))


class Egg:
    def __init__(self, surface, x, y, egg):
        self.surface = surface
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.egg = egg

    def draw(self):
        self.surface.blit(self.egg, (self.x, self.y))


eggs = []
while True:
    screen.fill((0, 78, 255))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            chickenx, chickeny = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            print('new egg')
            eggObject = Egg(screen, chickenx-50, chickeny-50, egg)
            eggs.append(eggObject)
            screen.blit(chicken, (chickenx,chickeny))

    for e in eggs:
        e.draw()

    screen.blit(chicken, (chickenx, chickeny))
    pygame.display.update()
```

This should work as expected. Feel free to ask questions if something is unclear. Hope this helped!

Comment: @Subhash Sharma You’re welcome :) I would really appreciate it if you accept the answer by clicking the check mark.